# How can I make a center-aligned text's with to be just the text's width?

Tags: css, alignment, width, center

Wondering how I can make centered text's width the width of the text?
Highlighted in red, it shows that the width is 100%.

http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/ktkdypyo/

CSS:

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 5vh;
    line-height: 1;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background:red;
    color:white;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your HTML structure like below and apply style for h2 as well.

```
  <div style="text-align:center"><h1>text is centered</h1><br />
   <h1>but the width is 100%.</h1><br/>
   <h1>How can I make it so that the width</h1><br />
   <h1>is only the widht of the text?</h1>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
h1 {
font-size: 5vh;
line-height: 1;
white-space: nowrap;
background:red;
color:white;    
display:inline-block;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ktkdypyo/3/)

Comment: Brilliant — Thank you. I have marked your answer as the correct one :)

Comment: Actually — one more question. How can I make it so that when I hover over any of those texts, it fades out and gets replaced by a different text?

Comment: If you want to replace text then you need to use jquey/javascript

Comment: well, I'm looking for a css only trick, but I modified this: any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/ktkdypyo/5/  isn't a way to use functions like ~, +, >, etc?

Comment: that'll be a great start for me— thank you :) however, when noticed that when I scale down the window, the text responds to the height of the window, but the line-height increases for some reason. any idea as to how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/ktkdypyo/2/ you can add span inside h1 tag and then just give red color to span

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    font-size:100%;
    font-family:helvetica;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;


}
span{
  font-size: 5vh;
    line-height: 1;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background:red;
    color:white;   
}


<h1><span>text is centered<span></h1>
<h1><span>but the width is 100%.<span></h1>
<br/>
<br/>
<h1><span>How can I make it so that the width</span></h1>
<h1><span>is only the widht of the text?<span></h1>
```

And your another question in the comments **How can I make it so that when I hover over any of those texts, it fades out and gets replaced by a different text?**
here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u7tYE/5060/

Comment: thanks for the solution, but when i scale down the window, the line-height increases. how can I fix that?

Comment: give the font-size in pixels  `font-size: 20px;`

Comment: but text needs to be responsive to the height. is there any way to solve this?

Comment: mediaquery.. if thats really very much required.. you can set different font-sizes for different heights.

Comment: thats a really awesome solution, but the line-height is still changing :/

Comment: no.. where is line height changing.. I dont see that in this fiddle

Comment: take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/u7tYE/5061/
you need to make sure you scale down the window of the code's result, not the browser window

Comment: define the font-size in `px`. then the line height wont change.. if you want line height not changing too much but still want font-size to be changing- try setting mediaquery for changing font.. things will work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68466/discussion-between-kenhimself-and-naeem-shaikh).

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your text in a span and apply the background-color in span instead of h1. You can't use the same element because they are block-level element. You will need to put an inline-block element in a block-element to get the result you want.

For example

```
<h1><span>this is the entered text</span></h1>
```

CSS

```
span {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: You're missing the point of the red background — when you highlight the text, regardless the red background is applied to span or h1, it still registers the width being 100%. aligning the text means it needs to have a left and right border — in this case, the border is the body & html.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the question well. I thought it was about text highlight. Anyway, the explanation about block-level and inline-block element is still valid.

Comment: Please don't apologize! Many thanks for the feedback anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Question is already answered but adding

```
margin: 0 auto;
display: table;
```

to the css gets the job done without changing the markup. I've tested it on ie, chrome, mozilla and opera, seems okay on all.

Comment: I heard using tables is a bad idea these days and has been recommended to me numerous of times that it should be avoided. do you know why?

Comment: but you're not using table here. you're having h1 behave like a `table` element. in your markup it's still `<h1>`. using <table> element for layout is not a good idea as explained here: [link](http://phrogz.net/css/WhyTablesAreBadForLayout.html)

Comment: oh I see, thank you for the suggestion. however, when I scale down the window, the text responds to the height but the line-height increases.. any idea how to fix it? http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/ktkdypyo/7/